# Laravel 5.8, validation fails on applying a custom rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation

This works perfectly fine. When passing a null value, the `nullable` tag does its job of ignoring the validation if email is null.

```
 Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'email' => 'nullable|unique:users,email|email|max:50',
 ])->validate();
```

Below code fails when a null value is passed. The `nullable` tag does not seem to work and the validation directly jumps to the `email` tag and fails the validation with error

> The email must be a valid email address.

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => [
            'nullable',
            'email',
            'max:50',
            Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($request->userId),
        ],
 ])->validate();
```

Comment: Did you tried to use `sometime` validation? You can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

Answer (score 0):

If you specify multiple validators the data must pass all of them, not just one. To work around this you can use `sometimes` as [@mare96](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542778/laravel-5-8-validation-fails-on-applying-a-custom-rule#comment101551887_57542778) suggested.

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => [
            'nullable',
            'email',
            'max:50',
            'sometimes',
            Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($request->userId),
        ],
 ])->validate();
```

Alternatively you could write your own rule as a custom class. In those cases you can choose to either implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` to only run the rule for non-empty values.

If you implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ImplicitRule` it will be run for empty values as well.

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#implicit-rule-objects)